# black cracks/ fragments across multiple objects in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, modifiers, error

In my render I have been working on there are multiple objects which have black "cracks" traveling through them, despite not being parented or part of the same mesh.

The normals are not inverted, the texture is procedural, and these "cracks" do not show up in preview render (despite subsurf modifiers having same viewport and render values). Here are some images of  the result:

[image: black crack right side]

[image: black crack left side]

The chassis has a subsurf modifier, followed by an edge split and a solidify. The tires (an entirely separate mesh being affected by seemingly the same fragmentation) have only a subsurf modifier. Both use smooth shading.

Final Note: These "cracks" only occured after I added keyframes as an attempt to render 4 different angles in a single sitting without having to start the render manually each time. These cracks now occur whether I render a single image without any keyframes on the dope sheet, or as an animation.

Any help in solving this issue would be much appreciated! Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some hidden extra geometry being rendered. Make sure you don't have any geometry that is hidden, but with rendering enabled (Alt+H will do).